# Workaround for no point clustering in ArcGIS Javascript API 4.7

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm working with the ArcGIS Javascript API v4.7 and I've run into a roadblock. I have several points on my map with the same coordinates. Therefore they show up exactly on top of one another with no way to access any of them but the one on top. Unfortunately, it looks like the v4.7 api does not yet have the clustering capabilities that the 3.x api had ([See this matrix](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/functionality-matrix/index.html))

I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions on other ways to deal with this issue, other than clustering. I'm seeing information on other ArcGIS tools, like the Desktop version, that use displacement methods on points. Most of these built in solutions (like arcpy or dispense markers) are not available in the javascript 4.x api.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146667)